# Extension method not updating object passed in

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I recently started to learn about LINQ and came across the `OrderBy` extension method. This initially excited me because the syntax seemed much nicer than the `Sort` method that we use all over the place for Generic Lists.

For example, when sorting a list of languages, we normally do something like:

```
neutralCultures.Sort((x, y) => x.EnglishName.CompareTo(y.EnglishName));
```

This works well, but I prefer the syntax of `OrderBy`, which only requires that you pass in the property that you wish to sort by, like so:

```
neutralCultures.OrderBy(ci => ci.EnglishName);
```

The problem is that `OrderBy` returns `IOrderedEnumerable`, but I need `List<T>`. So, I set out to extend the `Sort` method for `List<T>` using the same signature that is used for `OrderBy`.

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this List<TSource list, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    list = list.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList<TSource>();
}
```

This would be called like:

```
neutralCultures.Sort(ci => ci.EnglishName);
```

Maybe I'm overlooking a simple implementation detail, but this code doesn't work. It compiles, but doesn't return an ordered list. I'm sure I can refactor this to make it work, but I was just wondering why setting `list` within the extension method doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the behaviour I would expect. Imagine if such a thing were possible:

```
var c = myCustomer;
myCustomer.DoStuff();
if (c == myCustomer) // returns false!!!
```

Simply calling a method on an object (which is what an extension method looks like to the user of your framework) shouldn't change which instance the reference points to.

For your example, I would stick with Sort.

Comment: Note that this reasoning only applies to classes; structs *can* behave exactly like you state, even if they are immutable. The DoStuff() method (for a struct) can be `this = new Foo("mwahahaha");`

Comment: Thanks Matt, makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for simplifying it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've written Sort variants using a selector before - it isn't hard... something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<Foo> {
            new Foo {Bar = "def"},
            new Foo {Bar = "ghi"},
            new Foo {Bar = "abc"},
            new Foo {Bar = "jkl"}
        };
        data.Sort(x => x.Bar);
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Bar);
        }
    }

    static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(
        this List<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
    {
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        source.Sort((x,y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
    }

}
```

Comment: note it is pretty trivial to add an overload that accepts an `IComparer<TValue>` for custom comparer support.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because `list` is not passed by ref. Thus setting the `list` variable to another object doesn't alter where the original variable was pointing.

You might be able to do this (haven't tested it properly):

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this List<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var tempList = list.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList<TSource>();
        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(tempList);
    }
```

Comment: Nice thought, but I just tried adding the "ref" keyword, and it doesn't work with "this".

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly where I was going next with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the value of the local parameter variable called `list`, not changing the value of the caller's variable (which is what you are trying to do.)